# Set Series number according to user logged in

Tags: navision

I need to set a document number using the last series number used according to the user logged in the NAV system.

So I have the user1 and user2 and for the first user I want to use the series "MRVRPOS1" and for the second I want "MRVRPOS2"

[image]

I thought to create a var to save the last series number and set to the document number depending of the user ID

SeriesCode:=SeriesLine.GET("Series Code");

IF USERID='LACT-MIRA-POSMR01' THEN
"Document No.":=SeriesCode;

IF USERID='LACT-MIRA-POSMR02' THEN
"Document No.":=SeriesCode;

(I know the code below is not right, is just a example of what I want)

In my page the Source Table is gen Journal Line, where the Document number is set.

Comment: The code is not right for sure. So, what you want to know?

Comment: I'm trying to set in my page the journal name to one I've created but the document number is not updated.

https://us.v-cdn.net/5022383/uploads/editor/ci/c0qoknpt03u7.png

In the document no instead of "MRVRC180212" (of the general journal) I want the series number "MRVRPOSA180001".

Comment: @MakSim can you help me?

Comment: I can’t understand what you want to do.

Comment: What should happen if User3 has logged in?

Comment: we dont have a user3.. i jsut have user1 and user2

Comment: Can you create two Journal Templates or Journal Batches with different No. Series and ask users to use their own Template/Batch